# Why does List.AddRange accept T[] but doesn't accept IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, list, generics, ienumerable

So I was trying to refactor my code a little bit and I needed a method which checked if an array is null and then if it isn't add the items in that array to a list. I needed to add a lot of different items inheriting from the same class to a list of of that class.

I wrote this method:

```
private void AddItems<T>(T[] items) where T : SomeClass
    {
        if (items != null)
        {
            someList.AddRange(items);
        }
    }
```

this works fine, however my question is why does this:

```
private void AddItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) where T : SomeClass
    {
        if (items != null)
        {
            someList.AddRange(items);
        }
    }
```

not work?

> The latter example produces this error: "Argument 1: cannot convert from `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SomeClass>`"

```
List<SomeClass> someList = new List<SomeClass>();
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkR32.png)

Comment: please share definition of `someList`. Also by not working what do you mean? Compilation error? If so please provide which

Comment: That seems odd, as [the method declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netframework-4.7.2) is `List<T>.AddRange(IEnumerable<T>)`. In what way does it "not work"?

Comment: Please define "not work". Do you get an error? What's the error?

Comment: Depends on what version of .Net you're using.  Older ones did not support `IEnumerable<T>`. Though 6 does.

Comment: The latter code does not compile and produces the error which I added in the edit.

Comment: The definition of `List<T>.AddRange()` is an `IEnumerable<T>` though... `someList` must not be a `List<T>`

Comment: Maybe because your `someList` is not of type `List<T>`

Comment: Can´t reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9RqL7K

Comment: @juharr I dont think thats true at all.  Both `List<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` were added in 2.0.  So if the OP has access to `List<T>` then they have access to `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: works fine on my machine

Comment: I'm using .NET 3.5

Comment: That sort of explains it. Possibly support was added later than that. 3.5 is ancient.

Comment: @maccetture you're right, my tag was wrong

Comment: @DonAndre upgrade your local .NET to the latest. You can feel free to compile it against 3.5 but you will get all the new compiler features

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've added a screenshot of the error

Comment: @maccettura I might be thinking of some other method that use to only take an array instead of `IEnumerable` in an older version.

Comment: Why you don't use `IEnumerable<SomeClass> items` as parameter?

Comment: Downvoted and voted to close.  There is no [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @juharr Actually, now that you mention that I think I remember something like that too.  Althought I thought it was `string.Join` that had that weirdness

Comment: @TimSchmelter because I'm adding classes that inherit from SomeClass to the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with how arrays and generics work. You have a variable typed like this:

```
IEnumerable<SomeSpecificClass>
```

Where you know that `SomeSpecificClass` always inherits from `SomeClass`. You want to add all the items in that sequence to a `List<SomeClass>` using `AddRange()`. But `List<SomeClass>.AddRange` is specific; it wants exactly an `IEnumerable<SomeCass>`, and you can't directly cast from `IEnumerable<SomeSpecificClass>` to `IEnumerable<SomeClass>`. You can fix this with a simple `Cast<T>()`:

```
someList.AddRange(items.Cast<SomeClass>());
```

The question now is why the array works, and the answer is arrays are special in this way. They are more than just generics. You can directly cast a `SomeSpecificClass[]` to a `SomeClass[]`, and since `SomeClass[]` implements `IEnumerable<SomeClass>`, everything is already fine.

Comment: Yes, that was precisely what I was asking about, I know how to solve the problem. The question why does the first work and the latter doesn't, thanks!